# progress dialog spinner color not showing in some devices

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm defined progress dialog like this :

```
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

            if (newProgress < 100) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
                progressDialog.show();
            } else if (newProgress == 100){
                if (progressDialog!=null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
```

the style for progress dialog it's like this it has green spinner color and grey background :

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue_grey_800</item>
</style>
```

the problem is when it's launched in my friend phone Samsung Galaxy J2 Prime(Android 6.0) the progressdialog is showed but without spinner.

i've tested in android emulator using same os 6.0 it's showing no problem.

anyone could tell me the problem, i'm really new on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by the theme colors on the device. Try changing the colorAccent or setting the background for the ProgressDialog.

Comment: sorry can you give a detailed explanation, the background on that device is changed but the text still remain black and spinner has no color or not showing.

Comment: the dialog background or the activity/screen background has changed? The colorAccent value is defined in the Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert for the Galaxy J2, if that color is too close to the value of blue_grey_800, the spinner might not be visible. It's better to define your own value for both the ProgressDialog background and spinner color